VBA - unzip a folder that has password protected files - how to enter password when prompted
I am using the code below to unzip the folder, but the excel files within the zipped folder are password protected, so the macro stops when the prompt for password occurs.  How can i set a variable for the password to be automatically entered?
Sub UnzipAFile(zippedFileFullName As Variant, unzipToPath As Variant)

    Dim ShellApp As Object

    'Copy the files & folders from the zip into a folder
    Set ShellApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    ShellApp.Namespace(unzipToPath).CopyHere ShellApp.Namespace(zippedFileFullName).Items

End Sub


Do you mean each Excel workbook is protected with an "open" password?

I'm able to unzip a zip file with a couple of password-protected xlsx files, so maybe you mean you're trying to unzip a single Excel file?  I don't get any pop-up when I try that: it just fails.  Which makes sense.  If you know the password, then open the file in Excel first and remove the password on re-saving.  Than you can unzip it.
